# Значок в edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

У меня есть поле для ввода. В этом поле будет вводиться некая сумма. Пользователь должен просто ввести сумму, а значок рубля должен находиться на поле Edittext всегда и просто двигаться вправо в зависимости от того, как меняется сумма. Пример как в приложении СберБанк
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вешайте TextWatcher на поле ввода. В нужном методе добавляйте в конец строки символ валюты и устанавливайте курсор перед ним. ВОт тут пример есть: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5233488/3212712

Answer (score 1):

Используйте атрибут `suffixText` класса `TextInputLayout`

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:suffixText=" $">
    
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Some text" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: есть какой-то другой способ, этот не совсем подходит для редактирования

Comment: Можно редактировать, погуглите "styling textinputlayout and textinputedittext in android"